# What is the htaccess equivalent for: if cookiename not exists: deny from all

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to protect a directory based on the **cookie name**.
My question is: how can I protect this directory  with httacess?

I have tried this, but this isn't working:

```
# .htaccess file; NOT WORKING!!    

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name=specific_value; [NC]
RRewriteRule deny from all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name=specific_value [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=403,L]
```

This will return a 403 forbidden error for all incoming uris if the `%{HTTP_COOKIE}` test succeeds.

If you want to deny access to a specific directory  based on the `%{HTTP_COOKIE}` use the following instead

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name=specific_value [NC]
RewriteRule ^dirName/.*$ - [R=403,L]
```

Same as the first rule but this will deny access to a single directory path not the whole site.